# Why does a slow script cause my entire site to halt?

Tags: performance, lamp

I have a **PHP** script that uses `cURL` to load a file from another server.

The file is about 24MB. I understand why the script itself loading the file would take a bit to execute, however any request to the site while the script it running will hault until the script finishes.

This did not happen on our old shared server with the same script. The new server is a cloud server. I took it up to 10 nodes (6Ghz dedicated cpu, 3760MB ram, 2500GB bandwidth) and it had no effect on this issue.

I don't mind the script itself taking a long time to execute since it is going to be an automated task for a data feed. I can't have the whole site locking up while it runs though.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

---

**Update** it looks like this is only happening locally. If I try to load the site on a separate computer while the script is running it works as expected.

Comment: What's PHP running on?

Comment: @Shane it is a LAMP stack (Ubuntu lucid 10.04 x64, Apache 2) on a vps.net cloud server.

Comment: Which Apache MPM, and what module are you using for PHP (mod_php, fcgi, or other)?

Comment: @Shane, not sure, how can I find that out?

Comment: `apache2 -V` will give you the MPM.  For the module, check what's in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` - if both are in there, you'll need to look at your config to see which is used.

Comment: @Shane mpm is `Prefork`. There are a lot of results in mods-enabled but neither `mod_php` nor `fcgi` are in there. Is that the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I was not exact - `mod_php5` or `mod_fcgid`?

Comment: @Shane there is no mod_* at all. the entire output when I list the dir is: alias.conf       autoindex.conf  mime.conf         rewrite.load
alias.load            autoindex.load  mime.load         setenvif.conf
auth_basic.load       cgi.load        negotiation.conf  setenvif.load
authn_file.load       deflate.conf    negotiation.load  ssl.conf
authz_default.load    deflate.load    php5.conf         ssl.load
authz_groupfile.load  dir.conf        php5.load         status.conf
authz_host.load       dir.load        reqtimeout.conf   status.load
authz_user.load       env.load        reqtimeout.load

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to "ignore_user_abort(true)" and then use an HTTP redirect on the page to another page.

PHP 5 also has decent threading, that might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Now, the key question is: what else does your script do than fetches that file? Processes it and inserts the data to database? Perhaps in your old environment you had MySQL using InnoDB tables and in your new environment MySQL with MyISAM tables.

MyISAM requires full table lock during write operations instead of row-level locks InnoDB has, so that might cause your site to hang if your actual site is using same tables than the curl script.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good idea, the old site did process and save to a db like you said, currently the new one isn't doing that yet. Also the old environment was MyISAM and the new one is InnoDB.